Returning Task.CompletedTask vs void
I was going through an online video and the author had the below code:
public async Task CreateBookAsync(BookDto newBook)
{
    var book = new Book(newBook.Id, newBook.Title, newBook.Author, newBook.Price);

    await _bookRepository.AddAsync(book);
    await _bookRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
}

BookRepository:
public Task AddAsync(Book book)
{
    _dbContext.Add(book);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
{
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

I was not sure why AddAsync returns a Task and not just void, why have return Task.CompletedTask? Is it because the CreateBookAsync is using async Task, it's beneficial to keep all methods within using Task? Would it make a difference if it just returned void and the await was then removed from the caller method?

What is _dbContext? EF Core context?

there is no benefit to having created the AddAsync() method to wrap the call to _dbContext.Add() here.  DbContext.AddAsync() already exists, and exists for a special purpose only. Otherwise, DbContext.Add() (the synchronous one) should be used.  DbContext.AddAsync() is to allow special value generators

Does this answer your question? Async method without await or return


I was not sure why AddAsync returns a Task and not just void, why have return Task.CompletedTask?

Two possible reasons come to mind:

The BookRepository class implements an interface that has an AddAsync method. The implementation of the BookRepository.AddAsync could not be made really asynchronous, because (presumably) the _dbContext doesn't provide an asynchronous version of the Add. So the implementer having the option to either implement it synchronously or expose an asynchronous wrapper, chose wisely the former, because the later is evil.

The BookRepository class is part of a library that is expected to evolve. The author of the library anticipates that the _dbContext will acquire the ability to Add asynchronously in the near future. They decided to not expose an Add with synchronous signature, because then the users of the library would use this method, and their projects would not benefit automatically from a future release of the library that has incorporated the _dbContext's new asynchronous capabilities. They opted to expose a synchronous method with asynchronous signature, because they are thinking for the future.


